# Prove that $1 < \sum\limits_{n = 1001}^{3001} \frac 1 n < \frac 3 2.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, solution-verification, approximation

> Let $x = \sum\limits_{n = 1001}^{3001} \frac 1 n.$ Prove that $1 < x < \frac 3 2.$

**My attempt** $:$ What I did is as follows

By AM-HM inequality we have

\begin{align*} x =\sum\limits_{1001}^{3001} \frac 1 n & > \frac {(2001)^2} {\sum\limits_{n=1001}^{3001} n} = \frac {(2001)^2}{(2001)^2} = 1. \end{align*} and,

\begin{align*} x & = \sum\limits_{n = 1001}^{3001} \frac 1 n \\ & = \sum\limits_{n=1001}^{2001} \frac 1 n + \sum\limits_{n=2002}^{3001} \frac 1 n \\ & < \sum\limits_{n=1001}^{2001} \frac {1} {1001} + \int_{2001}^{3001} \frac {dt} {t} \\ & = 1 + \ln \left ( \frac {3001} {2001} \right ) \\ & = 1 + \ln \left ( 1 + \frac {1000} {2001} \right ) \\ & \leq 1 + \frac {1000} {2001} \\ & < 1 + \frac {1000} {2000} \\ & = 1 + \frac 1 2 = \frac 3 2.  \end{align*}

Hence we can conclude that $$1 < x < \frac 3 2.$$ Am I right? Please check it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Will Jagy why did you delete your comment? Think you have deliberately done it.

Comment: (+1) The proof is very neat, and I can't see any errors in it.

Comment: Also, pairing terms of the sum from the outside in
$$
\sum_{n=1001}^{3001} \frac1n>\frac2{2001}+\frac2{2001}+\cdots+\frac2{2001}+\frac1{2001}=\frac{2001}{2001}=1
$$